# Using a file with file names with paths in it as target for cp

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have some paths written like that

```
./20231023_155014.jpg
./20231023_155217.jpg
./20231023_155016.jpg
```

inside my file called rheuma.
Now I want to use this file as my input for the cp command and iterate through it.
Is it possible by default as a one-liner ?

Data should be copied from the smartphone via termux ssh and scp.

This command I would usually use…
`find . -mtime -1 -type f -exec scp {} /;`
It would be great but it does not work pretty well. So I need the solution from above or similar.

(Stuff like `… -exec scp {} /;` does not work in my environment)

Original wording of the question:
*How can I use a file with paths with the cp command*

EDIT: It is a file rheuma and in it are file names with paths like ./20231023_155014.jpg, and I am interested in running cp <path_from_file> somewhere.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you have a file `rheuma` and in it are file names with paths like `./20231023_155014.jpg`, and you are interested in running `cp <path_from_file> somewhere`? Then you mention some phone and how you're connected to it, is that related?

Comment: as this is a shell question, please tell us what shell you are using :)

Comment: `-exec scp {} /;` won't work in any environment, it should be `-exec scp {} \;` or `-exec scp {} +`. Assuming that's just a typo - what kind of non-POSIX environment are you running your code in where `find ... -exec` doesn't work and in what way does it not work?

Comment: BTW, `\;` is another way to write `';'` -- consider using the quotes instead of the slash if you find the slash confusing.

Comment: find ... -exec does not work with any ending:  ';'   \;   ^;
find: missing argument to `-exec' 
But thats not the key. It's all about the file containing paths as a input for cp or scp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In bash [not sure this is your environment], this should work for you:

```
for file in $(cat rheuma); do COMMAND $file ; done
```

where command is your function.   As some commenters point out, this won't work if you have extraneous whitespace in your input file, see their comments for some somewhat more complex approaches that can handle those cases.

You may also want to put xargs into your toolkit, it is useful as workalike to "find -exec" but ultimately you may hit a limit on the number of arguments it will process.   This technique looks like

```
cat rheuma | xargs COMMAND
```

Not that each line will just get appended to an iteration of COMMAND.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html

Again, if you have whitespace in your input file, see some of the comments for recipes for that.   I have very different ways of removing whitespace and I consider it a completely separate topic in fact.

Comment: that's a very fragile way of reading filenames. `while IFS= read -r file || [ -n "$file" ]; do COMMAND "$file"; done < rheuma` is better

Comment: xargs can't portably read files containing leading or trailing spaces; but some versions support `-d` or similar

Comment: To emphasize what jhnc said - [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Consider [edit]ing to put the xargs answer _first_ (and if at all possible, `-d $'\n'` (on GNU systems) or `tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0` (on either GNU or BSD systems) is worth suggesting; they're non-POSIX, but without one or the other, xargs is _very_ problematic)

Comment: Also, `$file` should be `"$file"`. (Granted, the set of places where the lack of quotes will be a problem and the set of places where `where anything in $(cat ...)` is a problem are tightly related).

Comment: for file in $(cat yaiks); do cp $file copied/ ; done
That works and solves the problem. Is there a more elegant solution without a direct loop?

Comment: some interesting comments, considering there's no mention of extraneous whitespace in the question.   The question is not "what is the best generic way to do X".   It is "how do I do X based on my example".    Based on the checkmark, mission accomplished.    There's a difference between "solving my problem" and "solving all problems of this type".

Comment: @BretWeinraub, we're here to create a [long-tail FAQ](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/); building a comprehensive, canonical resource is exactly the point, and has been since Stack Overflow was founded. As a teaching resource, it behooves us to teach good practices -- otherwise when people try to follow our examples out in the real world (where their code will encounter a wider variety of inputs than anyone is likely to think about when asking a question) we've led to the proliferation of bugs, and that's not a legacy I want to be part of.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - It's interesting to read your thoughts.   I am reminded of the Knuth quote "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".   My recipe will fail if there is garbage in the input.   But there is not garbage in the input.   I'm not sure we want to train an army of C-C C-V warriors pasting in code they don't understand, or need.   Better to understand what is whitespace, how it affects shell programming, how to detect it, and resolve the issue.   Knowledge is built layer by layer, so I am giving one layer.   I think this discussion adds something, so thanks for your perspective.

Comment: One last comment, if there's whitespace in your input file, you should repair and rewrite the file, not just leave the whitespace in the file as a speed bump for later [or for someone else].